# ASP.NET / C# Equivalent of Microsoft Source Code Analyzer for SQL Injection (MSSCASI_ASP)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-injection, static-analysis

[Microsoft Source Code Analyzer for SQL Injection (MSSCASI_ASP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954476) is a static code analyzer for classic ASP VBScript code that can help identify pages that might have a sql injection vulnerability.

That tool seems to only support vbscript ("The tool understands only ASP code that is written in VBScript"), and I think it only supports Classic ASP even for VBscript. I'm wondering if there is a tool with a similar approach capable of working with ASP.NET code, especially C# ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at the Microsoft Code Analysis Tool for .Net (CAT.NET)
You can find a download here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0178e2ef-9da8-445e-9348-c93f24cc9f9d&displaylang=en

Also it's discussed on the Microsoft Security Tools Blog

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a .NET version of that tool. If you are using parameters (which you should do most of the time,) you are not vulnerable to most of the SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Using sql parameters is definitely one of our coding guidelines. I can't be sure that we've actually used them in all cases, though. I was hoping an automated sweep could increase my confidence that we have used them in all cases, and/or help find the (hopefully) few places where we don't. If I had all the time in the world, I might do a manual security audit of all the code that touches the database. In practice, though, it seems unlikely I'll find time for that.